# Internal transfer question: prioritize job level or team?

Tags: new-job, internal-transfer

I'm facing a dilemma. Here is my situation.

- I have been working in my current team for 2+ years. And it is very likely that I'll be promoted mid 2021 if I stay in my current team.
- There is an opportunity for me to transfer internally to a very similar role in a better team (that team is the company's star team, and the team is in a better geographic location). But the downside is I may not be promoted if I transfer.

I'm working in a technical role in an internet company.

My question is, from the career development point of view, will a quick promotion weight heavier than working in a better team?

Comment: We can't tell you what you should do. Do what you think is best for you.

Comment: Why is it a better team? Better looking, better pay?

Comment: @joeqwerty Good point. I have rephrased the question.

Comment: **from the career development point of view, will a quick promotion weight heavier than working in a better team?** - Weigh heavier in what sense? Are you asking which is better for your career? Are you asking which is better at your current company? Again, I don't think this is a question we can answer. What will you tell potential employers? **"I moved to a better team."** How will they attach meaning and value to that statement? How will they gauge your suitability from that statement?

Comment: @Kilisi Thanks for the comment. The team is better because it contributes more to the company's total revenue, therefore face less risk of dismissal. And the team members are paid better.

Comment: **"I was promoted"** conveys information that people understand. It implies increased responsibilities and capability. **"I moved to a better team"** Conveys no useful information. It is a meaningless statement.

Comment: We don't even know what you want your "career" to be? Do you aim to be on the countries best team? Do you aim to be promoted to manage a team? Do you want to make enough money so you can back to university to study for another job altogether? We cannot make choices for you, but we certainly cannot make choices for you with no clear goal.

Comment: If you will be ***paid more*** in the new team, that is a ***promotion***.  Titles are totally meaningless, especially if this is software

Answer (score 4):

Higher job responsibilities are generally better for your career, not membership of a particular team. Once outside the company no one cares what team you were in usually.

It's the tasks and responsibilities that you will be showcasing on a CV.

Answer (score 3):

**"I was promoted"** conveys information that people understand. It implies increased responsibilities and capability.

**"I moved to a better team"** conveys no useful information. It is a meaningless statement.

So if you're asking which is better for your career, my opinion is that the promotion is better.

Moving to a better team doesn't tell anybody anything meaningful about your ability or your potential.